# ForEach only reading first line of text

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a text file where I have multiple text, on different lines which are unique. I have something like:

```
$submit = Get-Content submit.txt 

$submit| ForEach {
function Query 


{ ....}
return 0
```

However, it only reads the first line and parses it to the function. It parses it the same number of lines that are on the text file. How can I get it to iterate through each line one by one and pass the text to the function?

Comment: The `function` keyword _defines_ a function, it doesn't execute it. Please fix your code example (there's at least 1 `}` missing for it to be valid powershell code)

Comment: There is an ending } I just didn’t add it to my post. What should I use instead of function so it loops?

Comment: Please, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to define your function just once, *before* entering the loop:

```
# This will define the function so its available later, in the loop
function Query {
  param($Line)
  # ...
}

Get-Content submit.txt |ForEach-Object {
  # this actually executes the Query function
  Query -Line $_
}
```

Comment: But my function is using the variable that I’m parsing from that text file

Comment: Which variable? `$_`?